# What's the difference between PatchCreation element and Patch element in WiX toolset?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

In [this page](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/patch_building.htm) PatchCreation element is used and in [this page](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/patchwork) Patch element is used to create a patch. What's the difference between them? Patch element is documented in WiX 3.6 documentation and PatchCreation element is documented in WiX 3.0 documentation. Is PatchCreation element deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Patch`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_patch.htm) is used to build .msp packages using only WiX tools. [`PatchCreation`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_patchcreation.htm) is used to create .pcp files that you then pass to the MSI SDK tool [MsiMsp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create the .msp package.